# Is it possible to recover my heroku postgressql hobby-dev DB after a deletion?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I recently upgraded hobby-dev to hobby-basic on heroku using all the step of this link [upgrade hobby-dev to hobby-basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51211921/upgrade-hobby-dev-to-hobby-basic-on-heroku)

I forgot to remove the hobby-dev DB, my django app so were attached to 2 heroku postgres DB. May be  my app continued to store data into the hobby-dev. Yesterday  on heroku platform I deleted the hobby-dev without knowing, I lost a lot of precious data. I want to know if I can recover my first hobby-dev. Please help!

Comment: Thank you David, heroku support solved my problem

Comment: I reached the support here [link](https://help.heroku.com/), I first asked to re-attached my  hobby-dev DB,

Comment: I reached the support here [link](https://help.heroku.com/) after less than 3 days, and at once, they reply as you can you see  
In order for us to restore data, please:
Create a new Hobby Basic database Add-On attached to app
Send us an add-on name of that new Postgres instance
This is time-sensitive since the backup will expire within the next couple of days, so please let us know when Hobby Basic DB is provisioned so we can copy data from. heroku-support went ahead and restored back the data to my new database hobby-basic